# CaptureBAT equivalent on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, malware, dynamic-analysis, networking, wireshark

Hello RE community on stack !

I am a beginner, so please pardon any commonplace errors

I am looking to run CaptureBAT on a Windows 10 VM, to capture network activity of different kinds of Malwares

I specifically need to run CaptureBAT since it is capable of filtering out the noise from Windows' usual services

However, i cannot find any installer on the  internet for the utility

I have found a github repository [here](https://github.com/ph0sec/CaptureBAT-client) but i am not quite sure how to compile it

can  anyone suggest any good alternatives to CaptureBAT on windows 10 or tell me a method to run this tool on Windows 10 ?

i would be grateful for your kind help

P.S : alternatively i am open to using any other tool, except wireshark, that would help capture network activity of the  malicious executable. I am looking forward to the suggestions of this community in this regard

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use Microsoft Network Monitor tool to filter the traffic of a specific process.

[image]

Archive Download Link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865

EDIT: Figured out the problem with CaptureBAT, most likely because of it being 32 bit, while win10 is 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to CaptureBAT on Windows 10 is [FakeNet-NG](https://github.com/mandiant/flare-fakenet-ng).

Answer (score 1):

Really, if all your after is the procmon filters from CaptureBAT, go to the git hub page and download just them.  They will be about a decade old, though.  I guess they'll give you a start.  You can add to them where necessary:

https://github.com/ph0sec/CaptureBAT-client/tree/master/ExclusionLists